# Quartz Scheduler - Job Chaining with JobDataMap

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I'm new to Quartz Scheduler and have the following requirement

I need to have two jobs.  based on the first job response, the second job need to be triggered immedeately.

I read different appraches for jon chaining and after going through the list, I finally settled down for JobDataMap approach.

First Job :

```
public void method callJob()
JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(DataProcurementJob.class)
                                  .withIdentity("Job1, "JobGroup1")
                                  .build();

            JobDataMap jobDataMap = jobDetail.getJobDataMap();
            jobDataMap.put("NEXT_JOB", "com.abc.test.Jobs.DataLoadJob");
            jobDataMap.put("PARAM1", "VALUE1");
            jobDataMap.put("PARAM2", "VALUE2");

            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                             .withIdentity("DataProcurementTrigger1",                        "DataProcurementTrigger")
                              .withSchedule(
                            CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
                              .build() ;

            //Schedule it

            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail,trigger);
            scheduler.start();

}

Execute Method class : 
public job1Class implements job {
If (condition == false){
      keep running Job1
}
else 
{ 
Call Job2
}
}
```

I have implemented the above code, but second job is not getting launched.  I'm printing a statement in Job 2.

Can somebody please advise on how to invoke the secon job only once?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JobDataMap, You can try with JobChainingJobListener:

```
JobChainingJobListener chain = new JobChainingJobListener();
chain.addJobChainLink(job1.getKey(), job2.getKey());
```

You have to schedule your job1 and add job2 to the scheduler:

```
scheduler.add(job2, false);
scheduler.scheduleJob(job1, trigger);
scheduler.start();
```

and your job2 must be durable (param storeDurably).

Comment: How to chain more than 2 jobs, example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62727419/run-jobs-one-after-the-other-from-queue-using-quartz-scheduler